# sharePoint arcitecture custom action in list shown in pop up

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

[image: custom action]

this is an image of a sharepoint list action ,  the sending news letter is a custom action that i added , but when clicking on it , i want it to open a page not redirection, i want it to get a pop up action with a mask behind as the View item do

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is the modal framework in sharepoint 2010. You need to change your action javascript code.

Here is an article i've used in the past.

http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/Using-the-SharePoint-2010-Modal-Dialog.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to call ModalDialog Javascript function from your CustomAction rather than redirection.

Here's the URL with example of what you are looking for:

http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/Using-the-SharePoint-2010-Modal-Dialog.aspx